# Currency format for currency different than Locale

Tags: java, android

On Android, I'm trying to format some currency with a specific number format.

My number have to be formatted with the French formatting (`9 876 543,21`) but the symbol for the currency should be placed depending on the currency :

- `9 876 543,21 €` for EUR
- `$9 876 543,21` for USD

Here is my code right now (this uses `java.util` classes but the result is the same with `android.icu` package) :

```
final Double of = Double.valueOf("9876543.21");
final Currency usd = Currency.getInstance("USD");
final NumberFormat currencyInstance = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
currencyInstance.setCurrency(usd);
Log.d("test", currencyInstance.format(amount));
```

And the output is `9 876 543,21 $US` because for my NumberFormat is using a French locale.

Note: The Locale MUST be FRANCE (or FRENCH) to have the good number formatting and I actually don't know the currency code (EUR, USD or GBP for eg.), it's will be just a string from a webservice.

Is there a way to tell the formatter that I want the French number formatting but that it needs to respect the currency placement for the symbol ?

Comment: Are you sure about wanting the symbol according to the currency? From a quick skim of the net, the placement of the symbol seems to be determined by the display locale, not the currency (so trailing $ would seem correct in a French locale).

Comment: That's what I learned from reading around the net. But I've just been told to implement the currency formatting like this and I was wondering if it could be doable with the standard NumberFormatter. I should probably start lobbying with the "business" guys to simply format the currencies with the normalized format ...

Comment: Take a look at this library https://github.com/jpvs0101/Currencyfy

Answer (score 6):

this works perfectly, i think is what you are tring to achieve

```
    final Double of = Double.valueOf("9876543.21");

    NumberFormat currencyInstance = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(getLocalFromISO("EUR"));
    Log.d("test", currencyInstance.format(of));
    currencyInstance = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(getLocalFromISO("GBP"));
    Log.d("test", currencyInstance.format(of));
    currencyInstance = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(getLocalFromISO("SEK"));
    Log.d("test", currencyInstance.format(of));
    currencyInstance = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(getLocalFromISO("USD"));
    Log.d("test", currencyInstance.format(of));

private Locale getLocalFromISO(String iso4217code){
    Locale toReturn = null;
    for (Locale locale : NumberFormat.getAvailableLocales()) {
        String code = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).
                getCurrency().getCurrencyCode();
        if (iso4217code.equals(code)) {
            toReturn = locale;
            break;
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
}
//Prints  
//9.876.543,21 €
//£9,876,543.21
// 9 876 543,21 kr
//US$9,876,543.21
```

Comment: Hi, my problem is I don't know the currency in the code. I only get the ISO  code (USD, EUR, GBP) from a webservice so I can't use a proper locale for the NumberFormat.
And in your example, the output for USD should be in my case `$ 9 876 543,21` (french formatting with the currency symbol before the number).

Comment: i see, can't you just use a switch, or a nested if statement? if you get USD from the server you set `currencyInstance` to US if you get EUR you choose any euro country like France, since you only have a few i think this shouldn't be a problem

Comment: As this is a banking app, I can theoretically get any currency code like EUR, USD, SEK, DKK, CAD etc...

Comment: This is good to find the proper local to display the best currency symbol but It will still break the number formatting. I think what I want is simply impossible with the standard `NumberFormat`. Thanks for the effort, I will keep your piece of code in case I need to implement something really custom.